# Convert a character to a column name when using "dplyr::mutate"

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to dynamically create the name of a column and use it inside of `mutate`

1. My `df` has forecast months as "p1", "p2"
2. I want to calculate the variance to actual
3. The input I want to give is only the forecast period code, eg: "p1" to work out the answer

#### sample df

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          product = c("aa", "bb", "cc"),
      act_rev_mtd = c(100L, 110L, 120L),
     rev_fcast_p1 = c(100L, 100L, 100L),
     rev_fcast_p2 = c(110L, 110L, 110L)
  )

reporting_mth <- "p1"
```

This is what I have tried, which is not working:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(mtd_rev_var = act_rev_mtd - !!paste0("rev_fcast_", reporting_mth))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get()` instead of `!!` in order to search for an object by name:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(mtd_rev_var = act_rev_mtd - get(paste0("rev_fcast_", reporting_mth)))
```

The result is:

```
df1
  product act_rev_mtd rev_fcast_p1 rev_fcast_p2 mtd_rev_var
1      aa         100          100          110           0
2      bb         110          100          110          10
3      cc         120          100          110          20
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert it to symbol with `sym` from `rlang` and then do the `!!`

```
df %>%
    mutate(mtd_rev_var = act_rev_mtd - !!rlang::sym(paste0("rev_fcast_", reporting_mth)))
#     product act_rev_mtd rev_fcast_p1 rev_fcast_p2 mtd_rev_var
#1      aa         100          100          110           0
#2      bb         110          100          110          10   
#3      cc         120          100          110          20
```

---

Or pass it as strings in `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(paste0("rev_fcast_", reporting_mth)), funs(mtd_rev_var = act_rev_mtd - .))
```

Comment: I am going with `get` as it fits nicely in my pipeline. Thanks for showing how to use `mutate_at`, never thought that was possibe